# What part of the kernel loads the framebuffer module of PS3?

Tags: c, linux, video, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to figure out how the PS3 start its video driver.

What calls to `static int __init ps3fb_init(void)` in the [linux kernel source code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/ps3fb.c?a=arm#L1288)?

- What calls `insmod` on this module?
- Where does it happen in the souce code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ps3fb_init is called by module_init.

```
static int __init ps3fb_init(void)
{
        if (!ps3fb_videomemory.address ||  ps3fb_setup())
                return -ENXIO;

        return ps3_system_bus_driver_register(&ps3fb_driver);
}

[..]

module_init(ps3fb_init);
```

udev loads required modules during booting. From udev docs,

```
  - All kernel events are matched against a set of specified rules in
    /etc/udev/rules.d/ which make it possible to hook into the event
    processing to load required kernel modules and setup devices. For all
    devices the kernel exports a major/minor number, udev will create a
    device node with the default kernel name or the one specified by a
    matching udev rule.
```